# How to do calculation on row level with data frame in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame in python, and I want to do a simple calculation on row level. How can can I do it in Python?

Current Table

| product ct | cost1 | cost2 | cost3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10 | 100 | 20 |
| 2000 | 200 | 100 | 30 |

Calculation Concept

| product ct | cost1 | cost2 | cost3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10/1000 | 100/1000 | 20/1000 |
| 2000 | 200/2000 | 100/2000 | 30/2000 |

Wanted Output

| product ct | cost1 | cost2 | cost3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 0.01 | 0.1 | 0.02 |
| 2000 | 0.1 | 0.05 | 0.015 |

Comment: Isn't `20/1000`=`0.020`?

Comment: In general, pandas functions that apply across a column or row will have an `axis` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.filter` to get the required columns (If you have the static columns, you can manually assign them to a list), and then use `div` to divide, and finally assign back all the values to the selected columns:

```py
>>> cols = df[:0].filter(like='cost').columns.to_list()
>>> df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['product ct'], axis=0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   product ct  cost1  cost2  cost3
0        1000   0.01   0.10  0.020
1        2000   0.10   0.05  0.015
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `divide` along the required axis:

```
df[["cost1", "cost2", "cost3"]] = df[["cost1", "cost2", "cost3"]].divide(df["product ct"], axis=0)
>>> df
   product ct  cost1  cost2  cost3
0        1000   0.01   0.10  0.020
1        2000   0.10   0.05  0.015
```